# When was it decided that "Wolfram" was a portmanteau?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

In the final season of *Angel*, it is emphasized that "Wolfram" in the name of the law firm **Wolfram & Hart** is actually a portmanteau, and that the ancient founders of the firm were

> the Wolf, the Ram, and the Hart.

**Was this function of the name "Wolfram & Hart" planned from the beginning or was it retconned into the show's final season?**

Comment: I seem to remember around the end of season 2 (when they’re hanging out in Lorne’s dimension) that they find some somewhat-evil books there, with a wolf, a ram, and a hart on the cover. So at least the idea of the name corresponding to three animals was in the writer’s minds at that point.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : Ah, that's interesting.  I only remember it being spoken aloud in the final season by the demon-infused Fred.  You should write an answer. :-)

Comment: Saw this question's title in HNQs, assumed it was about Wolfram Mathematica :-P

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Season 2, the team visits Pylea where they encounter [Covenant of Trombli Holy Books](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Covenant_of_Trombli_Holy_Books) in the episode [*Through the Looking Glass*](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Through_the_Looking_Glass).

It's very brief, but we see the holy books:

[image: wolf ram]

[image: hart]

The team does notice the coincidence, but it isn't really spoken of again. From [the transcript](http://www.buffyworld.com/angel/transcripts/043_tran.html):

> Gunn:  "Like one of them priests the host was talking about.  These books belong to them, right?"
>
> Wesley closed the middle book and sees that it has the head of a male sheep engraved on its cover.
>
> Cordy:  "Well, yeah."
>
> Gunn:  "Look, you're the one going on and on about how you're the princess.  Can't you just make them translate 'em for us?"
>
> Wes closes the second book.  It has a wolf's head on the cover.
>
> Cordy:  "I guess I could. Yeah.  Why not?  Princess, not really taking a vote, is she?"
>
> Wes looks down at the images on the covers of the three books, rearranges their order.
>
> Cordy:  "I'll make a decree."
>
> Gunn looks down as well:  "Wolf - ram..."
>
> Wesley:  "And hart.  -  I'm not sure the priests can be trusted."

Whether or not it was a retcon at *this* point is unclear, since Wolfram & Hart first appears during the first season of the show, but the idea of Wolfram & Hart being a portmanteau was being established long before season 5.

Comment: Nice work --- thanks.

Comment: This must be the kind of dialogue that gives translators for dubbed versions nightmares.