# Is there an Angel reference in Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron, angel

I keep hearing things about Joss Whedon putting an Angel reference in the Avengers: Age of Ultron movie. However, I cannot find what it is!

What is it?

Comment: There is also a reference to ultron in angel. At the start of the first scene where wolfram and hart appears Lindsey mentions the Ultron account.

Answer (score 38):

[image]

In the *Age of Ultron* scene where Thor is freaking out due to Scarlet Witch's mind tricks, we see a reference to **Wolfram & Hart**, the demonic law firm from *Angel*.

(In the show, [we find out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116772/when-was-it-decided-that-wolfram-was-a-portmanteau) that the firm descends from three ancient demons: the Wolf, the Ram, and the Hart.)

Comment: is there a video?

Comment: @albusseveruspotter : The Wolfram & Hart cameo, and other references in *Age of Ultron*, can be found in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBQ43N6zwrM

Comment: I've seen "wolf", "ram" and "hart" come up someplace else in the Marvel universe but I can't remember where (I know it wasn't AoU because I haven't seen it). At the time I didn't remember that Whedon was "show-running Marvel" so I thought there was a larger wolf, ram, and hart reference going on.

Comment: Oh, the show Angel. I thought he meant the Marvel Comics hero Angel. Super confused for a minute there.

Comment: +1 This gives me geek-gasm. Never seizes to amaze me, Joss Whedon.

Comment: Sooo.. that places the movie in the Tommy Westphall universe, which in turn places the Agents Of S.H.I.E.L.D. show in the universe. Someone should update the list: https://thetommywestphall.wordpress.com/the-master-list/

Comment: @apollo:   *cease* and *seize* are not the same word.   I really doubt anyone is committed enough to their craft to induce a seizure in themselves just for your amazement.

Comment: @ThePopMachine /slow clap/ _I was on mobile_, must have some sort of _distraction_ while typing. Can happen, I can't say multilingual people don't experience these sort of things. Though you just _had to_ point it out. If it bothers you so much, flag it. Some mod might delete it. I'm not doing it. It will be an itch for you, I'm sure.

Comment: @apollo:   Nope, it's okay.   I was sort of joking because the resulting image is humorous.   (And we don't flag incorrect semantics)

Comment: @ThePopMachine Then today's lesson for newbies: _"Do not flag incorrect semantics!"_ I hope you had fun :)